# Compare array with object key/value by specific value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, comparison, key-value

I need to create a new object key/value. In it i need the values from the already existing key/value object and i need to add values that are only in the array.

The array:

```
[{ name: "Computer", name: "Car", name: "House", name: "Flower"}]
```

The object key/value:

```
{ computer: { title: 'Computer', color: 'Black' }, house: { title: 'House', color: 'Red' }}
```

So in this case the new object would need to be:

```
{ computer: { title: 'Computer', color: 'Black' }, car: { title: 'Car', color:'' }, house: { title: 'House', color: 'Red' }, flower: { title: 'Flower', color:'' } }
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this? I was thinking to loop over the array compare the values between them and extract the repeating ones, but i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: That new object isn’t syntactically valid. It’s not clear to me how you expect this to work in any case… the key `computer` is arbitrary? Are `1` and `2` meant to be literal keys corresponding to … what, the array index plus one? Is the `name` key arbitrary? I would have expected `{title: "name"}` or something. I am very confused!

Comment: @jcalz it can be same object as the previous one, i've updated it. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Not really, sorry.  It would be helpful if your code is a [mre] that, when you drop into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (click this link!)](https://tsplay.dev/NrG6Vm), clearly demonstrates your issue.  Your edited object is still not a valid JavaScript object; it has syntax errors.  And I still don't understand what operation you're trying to perform here. The `"car"` key seems to come out of nowhere.  Could you please spell out the relationship? Maybe post a few more examples of input/output?

Comment: @jcalz I found my mistake it was a set of extra brackets {}, please have a look now [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gbxmOBbAUwC4YAiAYRDwAcBXKAhUmAXwBoZtdCSLFmWAXQDcAKFCRYIAEYArVJxiga9RiWxQAllAA2xGAHJKKhggOtWYidBwEA7gHk5BYLDTZldU+phbd+oyovRnN2JUQfPz0SI0RQi1EgA)

Comment: Just in case you missed it:  I still don't understand what operation you're trying to perform here. The `car` key seems to come out of nowhere. Could you please spell out the relationship? Maybe post a few more examples of input/output?  From this one example it's difficult to tell which parts are static and which parts are dynamic.  Like, do we always copy from the `name` property of the elements of the array? Or is `name` arbitrary and it might be different in another array?

Comment: @jaclz I've added few more items in the object, and another value for color which needs to be added as well. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Are you... turning a string property value into a key by lowercasing the first letter?  Is that what's happening?  I think I need to disengage here, unfortunately. When I see something like `[{ name: "Computer", name: "Car", name: "House", name: "Flower"}]` it's clear that this code never made it near an IDE, and I can't take on the burden of resolving syntax errors in the question unless the question is *about* syntax errors.  Hopefully someone else will come along who can help you. Good luck!

Comment: This code is what i receive from the api, and yes the key is lowercase string property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made the assumption that that first array was meant to be an array of individual objects each with a key of `'name'` as in the `arr` array.

```
const arr = [ {name: "Computer"}, {name: "Car"}, {name: "House"}, {name: "Flower"}];
const objVal = { 
        computer: { title: 'Computer', color: 'Black' }, 
        house: { title: 'House', color: 'Red' }
        };
const expected = { 
        computer: { title: 'Computer', color: 'Black' }, 
        car: { title: 'Car', color:'' }, 
        house: { title: 'House', color: 'Red' }, 
        flower: { title: 'Flower', color:'' } 
        } 

let returnObj = {};

arr.forEach((element) => {
    const name = element.name;
    if (objVal[name.toLowerCase()]) {
        returnObj[name.toLowerCase()] = objVal[name.toLowerCase()];
    } else {
      returnObj[name.toLowerCase()] = {
        title: name,
        color: ''
      }
    }
});

console.log(returnObj);
```